# Wordpress 301 redirects , placement and wildcards in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

I have two questions about using 301 redirects for a Wordpress site.

The .htaccess file has the Wordpress generated code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress_ultimatum/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress_ultimatum/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have many redirects of the form:
`Redirect 301 /oldname.htm http://example.com/newname/`

Online I have found conflicting advice on where to add the redirects to the .htaccess file. Some sites say add above the Wordpress generated code in the .htaccess file, some say add below. Which is correct?

My second question is about wildcards.

I have pages on the old site with urls of the form:

`http://example.com/name-one.htm
http://example.com/name-two.htm`

I want to redirect both of these to the same page on the new site, i.e. to:
`http://example.com/newname/`

Is it possible to use a redirect of this form? :

`Redirect 301 /name* http://example.com/newname/`

Comment: for your 1st question you can add 301 code above `# BEGIN WordPress` line, because after `# END WordPress` 301 code does't worked for me I don't know why.